# Extract value between quotes after colon

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed

I would like to extract the value of a parameter, it is separated by a colon and both -parameter and value- are between double quotes.

I tried to do it with awk, but using colon as a separator doesn't work because of the colons you see in the value.

```
"param1" : "u:user1:A,u:user2:B,u:user3:A,g:group1:A,g:group2:C",
```

I just want to extract this : u:user1:A,u:user2:B,u:user3:A,g:group1:A,g:group2:C, in order to append a new value at the end with my script.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a double quote as the delimiter, you take the 4th field:

```
$ str='"param1" : "u:user1:A,u:user2:B,u:user3:A,g:group1:A,g:group2:C",'
$ value=$( cut -d'"' -f4 <<<"$str" )
$ echo "$value"
u:user1:A,u:user2:B,u:user3:A,g:group1:A,g:group2:C
```

Comment: Omg didn't see that... sorry to ask a so dumb question and thanks for your answer.

Comment: Could you explain the 3 "<" please ? I think I never saw it before

Comment: That's a form of redirection called a "here-string". (see https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Here-Strings) One `<` redirects input from a file; 2 `<<` redirects input from a delimited here-document; 3 `<<<` redirects input from a string.

Comment: Good to know! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

try following with awk and let me know if this helps you.

```
awk -F'"' '{print $4}'   Input_file
```